# Add Int Column Values Similar To Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a data structure similiar to:

```
Person | Counter
Mary       1
Mary       2
John       5
John       6
```

I am trying to **Group By** on the Person column, and add up the values for the counter, for each person. Meaning, I am trying to return:

```
Person - Mary - Has 3 Counters
Person - John - Has 11 Counters
```

This is my current effort, however it is not working:

```
SELECT ('Person - '+  ISNULL(NULLIF([Person],''),'NOT ASSIGNED') + 'Has') as Name, 
COUNT(*) Match, (SELECT COUNT(*) + 'Counters' FROM [MyTable] )  Total 
FROM [MyTable]
```

Comment: So you want to `SUM` the content of the Counter column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (Person VARCHAR(25), [Counter] INT)

INSERT INTO @DATA
SELECT 'Mary',1 UNION
SELECT 'Mary',2 UNION
SELECT 'John',5 UNION
SELECT 'John',6

SELECT 'Person - ' + ISNULL(Person,'Not Assigned') + ' - has ' + CAST(SUM([Counter]) AS VARCHAR) + ' counters'
from @DATA
GROUP BY Person
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a group by clause just as you stated, so something based on this:

```
SELECT Person, SUM(Counter)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Person
```

I didn't include the extra text from your original query to make it a bit more compact.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an aggregate function for this.

```
SELECT ('Person - '+  ISNULL(NULLIF([Person],''),'NOT ASSIGNED') + 'Has') as Name, 
       COUNT(*) As Match,       
       Sum(Counter) As Count
FROM   [MyTable]   
Group By Person
```

You were also missing an `As` in the second line.  The Sum Aggregate function will Sum all of the values for each group, in this case your counter.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `group by` ?

Answer (score 0):

Cheruvian's answer might be what you want, I can't tell exactly by your example, here is what I came up with just in case.

```
SELECT 'Person - ' + ISNULL(NULLIF(Person, ''), 'NOT ASSIGNED') + ' - Has ' + SUM(Counter) + ' Counters' As ReportOutput
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Person
ORDER BY Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a `GROUP BY` in a subselect, and then build the string using the results. Something like this:

```
SELECT ('Person - '+  myperson + ' Has ' + CAST(mycount  AS VARCHAR) + ' Counters')
FROM (SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF([Person],''),'NOT ASSIGNED') myperson, sum(counter) mycount
      FROM [MyTable]
      GROUP BY ISNULL(NULLIF([Person],''),'NOT ASSIGNED')) a
```

Comment: Invalid syntax, and missing a cast.